# How to properly share modified MIT library on GitHub?

Tags: python, github

So here's my situation:

I am working on chess software and to make it work I had to change **one line** of MIT-licensed library which I am using in my project. Modified library is in my virtual environment which is not included in my GitHub repository because I've read that is a bad practice to include venv into GitHub repo. Someday I'd like to share with my project to the chess world and I don't know how to handle this modified library. Normally without any changes I'd just include requirements.txt so a user could simply install it with pip. But here I can't do that because it'd download a library without necessary change. I have some ideas how to handle that but none of them seems optimal. Thanks in advance for any help!

PS. I know it's not strictly programming related question but honestly I don't know a better place to ask it.

Comment: Assuming the library is on GitHub as well, I'd recommend forking it; you could then point your `requirements.txt` at e.g. `git+https://github.com/yourusername/librarything.git@yourbranch`, but better yet, you could consider making a PR to include your change in the upstream repo.

Comment: Thanks! As for PR, someone else made it already but it stays not merged for a month and last accepted merge was several months ago. So I am afraid this lib is not supported for some time. Thanks you sir for the fork solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can just fork the library and point your requirements.txt to e.g. `git+https://github.com/yourusername/librarything.git@yourbranch` for the time being.

(Via my comment.)

Comment: the user needs `git` for this to work. in case users might not have `git` installed, i like to use `https://github.com/yourusername/librarything/tarball/yourbranch`